# Avoiding html entities in .mode html

Tags: sqlite, html-entities

I'm trying to use `.mode html` in `sqlite3` to create an html table. I want to create a link that looks like `<a href="http://assets.example.com/hardware/600">EXAMPLE05593</a>` as the last column in the table.

I've got an sqlite database that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE assets(
    "model_name" TEXT,
    "model_number" TEXT,
    "manufacturer" TEXT,
    "asset_tag" TEXT,
    "id" TEXT                                                                                                          
);
```

Let's say that my table looks like this:

```
model_name  model_number  manufacturer  asset_tag     id                                                          
----------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ----------                                                  
Meraki Z1   Z1            Cisco         EXAMPLE05108  115                                                         
us-24-500w  NULL          ubiquiti      EXAMPLE05348  355
```

My query looks like this:

```
select
    model_name,
    model_number,
    manufacturer,
    '<a href="http://assets.example.com/hardware/'
        || id
        || '">'
        || asset_tag
        || '</a>'
    as asset_tag
from assets;
```

When I set `.mode column`, I get this:

```
model_name  model_number  manufacturer  asset_tag
----------  ------------  ------------  -----------------------------------------------------------------
Meraki Z1   Z1            Cisco         <a href="http://assets.example.com/hardware/115">EXAMPLE05108</a>
us-24-500w                ubiquiti      <a href="http://assets.example.com/hardware/355">EXAMPLE05348</a>
```

when I run it in `.mode html`, quotes, `<` and `>` are all replaced with html entities, so I'm getting

```
<TR><TH>model_name</TH>
<TH>model_number</TH>
<TH>manufacturer</TH>
<TH>asset_tag</TH>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Meraki Z1</TD>
<TD>Z1</TD>
<TD>Cisco</TD>
<TD>&lt;a href=&quot;http://assets.example.com/hardware/115&quot;&gt;EXAMPLE05108&lt;/a&gt;</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD>us-24-500w</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD>ubiquiti</TD>
<TD>&lt;a href=&quot;http://assets.example.com/hardware/355&quot;&gt;EXAMPLE05348&lt;/a&gt;</TD>
```

rather than

```
<TR><TH>model_name</TH>
<TH>model_number</TH>
<TH>manufacturer</TH>
<TH>asset_tag</TH>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Meraki Z1</TD>
<TD>Z1</TD>
<TD>Cisco</TD>
<TD><a href="http://assets.example.com/hardware/115">EXAMPLE05108</a></TD>                                        </TR>
<TR><TD>us-24-500w</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD>ubiquiti</TD>
<TD><a href="http://assets.example.com/hardware/355">EXAMPLE05348</a></TD>                                        </TR>
```

Ordinarily, this would be the right thing, but I *want* to do html injection. I don't want those characters replaced with their respective entities. Is there a way to specify literal text in `.mode html`?

Answer (score 1):

What about decoding the string after getting it from your query? This way you could also sanitize your generated HTML before rendering or returning it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I'd prefer to leave the html escaping enabled for everything but the `asset_tag` column.